# Jquery template plugin refuse to replace my marker?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to replace some marker in my jquery template with values from my database and I pick up a json encoded array but my templates remains empty? Here is my jquery code:

```
    $j.get(url, function(json) {
       var singleview = $j('#tx-charbeitsbeispiele-pi1 #singleview');

       singleview.append($j("#singleviewTemplate").tmpl(json).css({
         "display": "block"
        }));
     }
```

My json_encoded data:

```
   "{"header":"Lorem Ipsum Header","bodytext":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
    consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et  
    dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo 
    dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est 
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing 
    elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam 
    erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea   
    rebum.Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor 
    sit amet."}"
```

My jquery template:

```
   <script id="singleviewTemplate" type="text/html">
     <div class="singleview">
         <h3>${header}</h3>
         <p>${bodytext}</p>
     </div>
   </script>
```

My stylesheet:

```
#singleview 
{
    position: relative;      
    float: left;          
    width: 1200px;        
    height: 800px;                
    background-color: #ffffff;    
    margin-left: 15px;        
    margin-top: 0px;         
    margin-bottom: 0px;       
    margin-right: 0px;        
    padding: 0px;        
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: What human-like behaviour for a piece of code to **refuse** to do something. Somehow I think that in the end the keyword will be **misuse**.

Comment: @MihaiStancu: Could it be that I need an JS object? I pick up an json_encoded array?

Comment: What is the result of `alert(json)`? it should be `[object Object]`. If it is instead a json string, you need to either return proper json headers, or set the datatype of your request to json. `$.get(url,handler,"json");`

Comment: Your JSON has line returns in it. It might just be from pasting it here, but make sure you don't have those in your production code. Otherwise your JSON will not parse.

Comment: use console.log(json) to check if it's an object or a string. Or look at the net console if it has a JSON tab.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the Jquery function to getJSON because the data type of the ajax request wasn't json but only text:

```
 $j.getJSON(url, function(json) {
   var singleview = $j('#tx-charbeitsbeispiele-pi1 #singleview');

   singleview.append($j("#singleviewTemplate").tmpl(json).css({
     "display": "block"
    }));
 }
```